# htaccess redirect to language folder with another redirect to php handler

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect my site from http://www.masterflooringtampa.com to go automatically to http://www.masterflooringtampa.com/en/ . I have been able to change my htaccess to do everything I needed except that. Please keep in mind that I use RewriteRule ^en/?$ index.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L] to direct to the correct php handler. Any htaccess expert can point in right direction? Also, if you have a shortcut or way to set up a formula to clean up the script (i'm just doing brute force, every url/link on its own approach that works but is not very elegant) I would be greatly appreciated.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

  # defaults to the english site

  RewriteRule ^en/?$ index.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^es/?$ index.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]

  RewriteRule ^en/products/?$ products.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^es/products/?$ products.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^en/services/?$ services.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^es/services/?$ services.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^en/about/?$ about.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^es/about/?$ about.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^en/contact/?$ contact.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^es/contact/?$ contact.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]

  RewriteRule ^en/floors/hardwood/?$ floors/hardwood.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^es/floors/hardwood/?$ floors/hardwood.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]

  RewriteRule ^en/floors/carpet/?$ floors/carpet.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^es/floors/carpet/?$ floors/carpet.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]

  RewriteRule ^en/floors/laminate/?$ floors/laminate.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^es/floors/laminate/?$ floors/laminate.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]

  RewriteRule ^en/floors/tile/?$ floors/tile.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^es/floors/tile/?$ floors/tile.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]

  RewriteRule ^en/floors/vinyl/?$ floors/vinyl.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^es/floors/vinyl/?$ floors/vinyl.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you're asking then it seems like your site is working as it should do

And to clean your code you can replace your code with this

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# defaults to the english site

RewriteRule ^en/?$ index.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/?$ index.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(en)/([a-zA-Z])/?$ $2.php?lang_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(es)/([a-zA-Z])/?$ $2.php?lang_id=2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(en)/([a-zA-Z])/([a-zA-Z])/?$ $2/$3.php?lang_id=1[NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(es)/([a-zA-Z])/([a-zA-Z])/?$ $2/$3.php?lang_id=2[NC,QSA,L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is working as intended. However, my problem is that I don't want Google to index http://www.masterflooringtampa.com but http://www.masterflooringtampa.com/en instead. I have a xml sitemap with alternates; however, currently traffic goes directly to http://www.masterflooringtampa.com and I would like to have that automatically go to http://www.masterflooringtampa.com/en by making a htaccess change. Hope I explained a bit better now